# writing to a pointer but the compiler still complains unused variable

Tags: go

The following code causes a compilation error:

> main.go:8:9: p declared and not used

```
package main

func main() {
    pointers := make([]*int, 5)

    a := 1 // create an int

    for _, p := range pointers {
        p = &a
    }
}
```

Writing to `p` doesn't count as using it?

Comment: No, because the value is never read, the write is pointless.

Comment: Remember that `p` is just your loop variable. Writing to `p` has no impact on your `pointers` slice or any of its elements.

Comment: Dunno why the downvotes.  It is obvious once you know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P is only scoped to the loop block and essentially gets a copy of a `pointers` slice element every time it goes through the loop. This would work though:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    pointers := make([]*int, 5)

    a := 1 // create an int

    for i := range pointers {
        pointers[i] = &a
    }
    fmt.Println(pointers)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/10cCFs3r5p8)